Delete all the columns from a very large file which satisfy a specific condition
I have a very large file of size approx. 5-10 GB.
The file will have 2 types of lines:

Lines starting with "#define CHAR_DEF"

Lines starting with "% "


Format of "% " lines:
%  <element 1> <element 2> ....  
A valid "% " is when  matches number of elements following it.
Eg. Valid:
% 5 A B C Df E city# plant#
Eg. Invalid:
% 5 A Bb Cc DD f Ee city# plant#
For our use case we need to consider "#define CHAR_DEF" lines and valid "% " lines.
Invalid "% " lines should be ignored and the file processing should stop if any other "#define " line is encountered.
Task is to identify the columns for which all the values are "N" and remove those columns from the file.
And based on the number of columns removed  should also be updated in each valid "% " lines.
Eg. InputFile.txt
#define CHAR_DEF header1 header2 h3 h4 h5 h6
% 6 N 1.2 r e N N city# plant#
% 6 N 2 3.2 r N x city# plant2
% 7 y w 2.3 3 d w c city# plant3 <invalid line>
#define CHAR_POINT h1 h2 h3 h4 <processing should stop here>
% 4 X h 1 1.2

Eg. OutputFile.txt
#define CHAR_DEF header2 h3 h4 h6
% 4 1.2 r e N city# plant#
% 4 2 3.2 r x city# plant2

Explanation:
Column: header1 and h5 were removed because they had N as their value in all valid "% " lines.
The line starting with "% 7" was not processed since it was not a valid line.
And execution stopped at just before "#define CHAR_POINT" line.
I have to do it with an algorithm which is time and memory efficient, since the size of the file would be very large. And hence need to make use of go routines.
Thanks in advance.

In term of memory, use bufio.NewScanner(file) to read the file in steaming no matter the file size. For writing use bufio.NewWriter(file) and writer.Flush()

"And hence need to make use of go routines." This workload seems like it is IO bound, not CPU bound, so adding goroutines won't actually help you much. Sure, you can have one routine to read, one to check validity and one to write, but the "read" and "write" routines will be waiting for eachother constantly and the "check validity" routine will so little that overhead of the routines may will cost more than you gain.

First try a simple read next line process next line write valid line repeat program to see how long it takes on a shorter file. That will give you an idea of how long it will take to process the whole file. It will also allow you to test possible improvements.
